# Cannot install Ruby AMQP Gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Currently, I have installed Ruby (ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) ) on my Ubuntu 11.10.  Wanted to install the AMQP gem using "sudo gem install amqp".  But it fails with the following error message :

```
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing amqp:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
    checking for main() in -lssl... no
    checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
    checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
    checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... yes
    checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... yes
    checking for rb_thread_check_ints()... yes
    checking for rb_time_new()... yes
    checking for sys/event.h... no
    checking for epoll_create() in sys/epoll.h... yes
    creating Makefile

    make
    compiling ed.cpp
    make: g++: Command not found
    make: *** [ed.o] Error 127


    Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0 for inspection.
    Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/ext/gem_make.out
```

Would appreciate if someone could help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to compile native extensions, you need a compiler. Just install g++ and friends using:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

and try again.

Comment: Thank you sir. I was under the assumption that the compiler comes packed with 11.10.  Appreciate your help.